# Ubuntu 18.04 -- USB flash drive automatically mounts for one user only, how to get access for other users?

Tags: 18.04, usb, permissions, mount, automount

When I insert a USB drive in my PC only one user (called e.g. `foo`) gets it automatically mounted in its `/media/foo`. Another user, `bar`, does not have it in `/media/bar`, neither can it access `/media/l/VOLUME1`. I'd like all users to be able to read and write to USB drives.

I can't even figure out what is the daemon that mounts it, I've no evidence it's `automount`, neither I'm sure it is it. I can see no relevant lines in dmesg or syslog -- it shows there was a new device but nothing about mounting.

If I go the GUI way, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB#User_Privileges is not helpful either: I'm not sure how to I "go to System->Preferences->Removable Drives and Media".

Comment: You can configure mounting options with the Disks aplication.

Comment: That looks like for individual disks. I'm after a newly inserted external USB drive